# Need a way to display .evtx (Event Log) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-log

I've been trying to find an answer for this for awhile, but can't seem to find one. I need to display Event Log files in a WPF application, with C#. I can easily access the files, but I don't know how to display in WPF window for a desktop app. I have the code to access the EventLog files.

Any information would be great!

```
            EventLog[] remoteEventLogs;
          
            remoteEventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs(eventpath);

            foreach (EventLog log in remoteEventLogs)
            {
                
            }
```

Comment: You can add each log line\s into an ObservableCollection<string> in a class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged(This will be your ViewModel class). In Window.xaml add ListBox with ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionPropertyName}" and in Window.xaml.cs add DataContext=new YouViewModelClass().

Comment: Can you show example of adding each line into OC<string> in INotifyPropertyChanged class? The .xaml is pretty straight forward, but I'm relatively new to C#

Comment: You have here nice documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 And here nice tutorials: https://www.wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html https://riptutorial.com/wpf/example/992/basic-mvvm-example-using-wpf-and-csharp

Comment: Also, specifically observable collection: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/#:~:text=WPF%20ObservableCollection,the%20UI%20is%20automatically%20updated.